# Mobx state tree observe not working as expected

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

```
const Player = types.model({
    game_object: types.frozen()
});

const Zone = types.model({
    players: types.map(Player)
})
.actions(self => ({
    addPlayer(params) {
        const playerGameObject = new PlayerGameObject(params);
        const newPlayer = Player.create({ game_object: playerGameObject })
        self.players.set(params.socket_id, newPlayer)
    }
}))
```

Later on I have

```
observe(store.zone, "players", change => {
  console.log("Store zone players changed!!", change)
})
```

I am not sure why this isn't working. I've tried a similar thing with a string field instead of a Player and it did work!

Here's the code sandbox!

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wave-wiy74?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Do you think you could create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/)? It's hard to say what the error might be without seeing what `store` is in your example.

Comment: @Tholle I just did that!

Comment: Great. You want to change to `self.players.set(params.socket_id, newPlayer);` since `players` is a map and not a regular object. That still doesn't make the `observe` listener run, but `observe(store.zone.players, (change) => {});` works. I'm not sure why, maybe you can use [any of these APIs until it's resolved](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/concepts/listeners)?

Comment: Wow thank you! That is very helpful @Tholle